# Why NPN switch doesn't have voltage?

Tags: transistors

this is probably dumb question, but I am trying to self-study electronics and cannot figure out, why this circuit has only 161mV on resistor. From what I understand, 1V on base should be enough to make collector-emitter basically a short circuit, so there should be 5V on resistor. What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 5):

> From what I understand, 1V on base should be enough to make
>   collector-emitter basically a short circuit, so there should be 5V on
>   resistor. What am I doing wrong?

1 volt between base and emitter usually turns on the transistor reasonably well (but beware of putting too much current into the base).

The trouble is with an emitter follower (like your circuit) is that as soon as the transistor starts to conduct, the emitter voltage rises and cuts down the base-emitter voltage hence, the emitter can never rise higher than what is applied to the base.

But it's a bit worse than that because you need anything between 0.5 volts and 1 volts to make a decent base current and that means the emitter voltage must be about 0.7 volts lower than the base voltage AND if you apply 1 volt to the base, the emitter might only reach 300 mV.

The above applies to NPN transistors and, with some thought also to PNP transistors.

Comment: Good answer. I just want to emphasize that it's the voltage **between base and emitter** that is important, not the voltage **on the base**. New users seem to miss this detail pretty often.

Comment: Oh right, that actually makes sense. Thank you. One more question if I might. When I increase base voltage to for example even 15V (so it should be enough), I will get only 2,63V on resistor. Why is that?

Comment: @user3048782 a real transistor would melt at that voltage on the base - current would flow from base to collector and drive amps into the 5 volt power source. That current is only limited by the device failing. You can do daft things in sims and they will attempt to give an answer of course!

Comment: move your resistor between collector and +5V and see the difference!

Comment: Great, if I do that, the resistor has more voltage.  Still, how do I achieve the same voltage as is collectors? Is that possible?

Comment: @user3048782 who are you addressing your comment to? You need to prefix a comment with "@somebody" to direct it.

Comment: @szulat Great, if I do that, the resistor has more voltage. Still, how do I achieve the same voltage as is collectors? Is that possible?

Comment: @user3048782 just in case you don't get a reply I'll step in. The sad news is that you will never get a BJT operating like the contact of a relay - it will never properly turn on if the load demand is great. MOSFETs are better because they will turn on (some of them) to as low as 1 milli ohm. But, you have to have the load in the drain circuit and not the source circuit unless you drive the gate higher than the supply rail.

Answer (score 1):

Your base voltage is set by your circuit. Since the emitter voltage, as seen through the emitter resistor, allows the base-emitter junction to be forward-biased, that junction will act somewhat like a diode and develop approximately \$700\:\text{mV}\$ across it. (More one that number in a moment.) Broadly speaking, this means there would only be about \$300\:\text{mV}\$ left over as a voltage drop across the emitter resistor.

The collector voltage is also set by your circuit. In this case, the collector voltage reverse-biases the base-collector junction. This is the usual way of operating a BJT in its active mode: the base-emitter junction forward-biased and the base-collector junction reverse-biased. So there is nothing particularly noteworthy here, except to say that this BJT is operating in its commonly-used ***active*** mode.

Your expectation about the emitter voltage being close to the collector voltage is what happens when a BJT is in ***deep saturation***. Not active. So your expectation is simply wrong, given this ***active*** mode operation.

Deep saturation occurs when the base-collector junction is forward-biased. This means that the collector voltage (for an NPN) would need to be ***below*** the base voltage. But it's not. The collector voltage is well above the base voltage. Because the base-collector junction here is reverse-biased, the BJT is not saturated but is active. So your expectation is simply wrong.

What happens in this circuit is that the base is set to \$1\:\text{V}\$ and the emitter, being part of a forward-biased PN junction, will be about \$700\:\text{mV}\$ lower, or at about \$300\:\text{mV}\$. This is a very tentative estimate, though. But it is a first-cut approach.

With this first estimate of \$300\:\text{mV}\$ across \$R_1\$, we'd estimate a current in the resistor of about \$300\:\text{mA}\$. But a small signal BJT's base-emitter PN junction uses \$700\:\text{mV}\$ when the collector current is more like \$4\:\text{mA}\$. That "diode" voltage increases by about \$60\:\text{mV}\$ for each factor of 10X in the collector current. Since the first estimate is about 100X as high, this means approximately \$2\times 60\:\text{mV}=120\:\text{mV}\$ more is required, so we now should re-estimate that the base-emitter PN junction requires closer to \$820\:\text{mV}\$ across it. This leaves only about \$180\:\text{mV}\$ across \$R_1\$. And that lowers the \$R_1\$ current to about \$180\:\text{mA}\$. That is a lot closer to what you show.

Note that the BJT still isn't saturated because the collector voltage is above the base voltage, thereby reverse-biasing the base-collector junction. So the BJT's collector and emitter voltages do not need to approach each other as they would, if saturated.

If you want to observe both voltages getting near each other, add a collector resistor of about \$27\:\Omega\$. That collector resistor will drive the collector's voltage downward so that it will be below the base voltage and allow the BJT to saturate.